# Get inner object from array

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component called `MovieSearchComponent`. This imports a service `MovieSearchService` and a model `Movie`.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'movie_search',
  templateUrl: './movie_search-component.html',
  providers: [MovieSearchService]
})

export class MovieSearchComponent{
  movies: Movie[] = [];

  constructor(private movieSearchService: MovieSearchService){};

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getMovies();
  }

  getMovies(){
    this.movieSearchService.getMovies()
      .subscribe((response)=>{
        this.movies = response;
        console.log(this.movies)
      });
  }
}
```

The service.

```
import {Movie} from "../movie";

@Injectable()
export class MovieSearchService{

  private results = {};
  private api = '***7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4';
  private  url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=' + this.api + '&language=en-US&query=Batman&page=1&include_adult=false;';

  constructor(private  http: Http){}

  getMovies(): Observable<Movie[]>{
    return this.http.get(this.url)
      .map(res => res.json())
  }
}
```

The template:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let movie of movies.results">
      {{ movie.title }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This does show all the titles from the movies that are returned from the service. But I have to select the result array which has all the movie objects in the template, which doesn't look right to me.

When I change the `console.log(this.movies)` to `console.log(this.movies.results)` in the `MovieSearchComponent` I get the error `property 'results' does not exist on type Movie[].`

This is the movie model:

```
export class Movie{
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public title: string,
  ){}
}
```

So why can't I use `console.log(this.movies.results)` when I can use it in the template.

Comment: Use interface :) I see no need for class here.

Comment: @AJT_82 To what end? How would that help with the problem? What class? Do you mean I should use an interface instead of the Movie model?

Comment: @AJT_82 why would you use interfaces to model your business domain? Interfaces represent contract, why would you wanna make `Movie` a contract?

Comment: @AJT_82 you are free to express your opinion, but don't forget to take into account relevancy and correctness

Comment: @Dummy Well I thought it was relevant to present this other option (opinion ?) to the code, and also to point out that the intialization of the objects to class is missing. Maybe sounded blunt, wasn't my intention though. Better delete them so that I'm not offending anyone :D

Comment: @AJT_82 what I was trying to convey was your suggestion to use interface to model a movie is not correct but you didn't seem to catch it and your suggestion had nothing to do with the question, even the OP said so (irrelevancy)

Comment: @Dummy Well the error would be gone with that tho, so relevant in that case :D Oh geez, well often see similar suggestions here on SO, but I'm not looking on how relevant that comment is, I see nothing wrong with them. But I'll keep your comment in mind ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because results is not defined in Movie Class.

Change your getMovies method to:

```
 getMovies(): Observable<Movie[]>{
    return this.http.get(this.url)
      .map(res => res.json().results)
  }
```

Comment: Now the `getMovies` function in the service returns the `.results` array from the json response?